# Amazon AWS bucket policy - Safari browser not sending referer information

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, safari

I have the following AWS bucket policy to restrict access to my Amazon S3 urls:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allowinmydomains",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.example.com/*",
                    "http://example.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Givenotaccessifrefererisnomysites",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.example.com/*",
                    "http://example.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

The above bucket policy works on all browsers, except for Safari. Doing research online, it's supposedly not working due to the Safari browser not sending any referer headers.

Any way to make this bucket policy work for all browsers, or is there another approach to denying access to the Amazon bucket to prevent hotlinking and downloading of files from outsite my site?

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you found information about Safari not sending Referer header? Have you really observed this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following bucket policy. You'll need to make sure your ACLs don't allow public access to your files and that you don't have any additional rules in your bucket policy that would allow access otherwise (by bypassing these rules):

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Id":"Bucket policy",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow GET requests referred by www.example.com and example.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{
          "aws:Referer":[
            "http://www.example.com/*",
            "http://example.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid":"Allow GET requests that don't specify a referrer (e.g. from Safari, Flash, etc.)",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "Null":{
          "aws:Referer":true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to force the [referrer](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Meta_referrer) for Safari:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="always">
```

or:

```
<meta content="origin" id="mref" name="referrer">
```